# Highcharts date inaccuracy

Tags: javascript, date, time, highcharts

The chart displays the wrong date at the data point, I would like the chart to display the correct date with the data label at the bottom. (see attached)[image: Chart Display]

I would like the date displayed in the hover over to be the same as the date displayed at the datapoint on the xAxis

Here is the code that I have for this chart

```
xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            min:new Date(new Date().getFullYear(),0,1).getTime(),  // new Date().getTime()-365*24*3600*1000*.75,
            max : new Date().getTime(),
            labels:{
                step:1
            }
        },
```

Comment: your expression returning 31 Dec2015 in GMT new Date(new Date().getFullYear(),0,1).getTime()  change it to new Date(new Date().getFullYear(),1,1).getTime()

Comment: what does new `Date(new Date().getFullYear(),1,1).getTime()` signify? I have tired the expression and this has not changed the chart

Comment: Define what you mean by "wrong date". It will show the date of the data point. The axis will round the tick placement to the start of various periods of default (1st day of the week, first of the month, first of the year, etc). So, if your data point is for December 31st, there is nothing inaccurate happening. The solution depends on the specifics of what behavior you want from the chart and your data.

Comment: Thank you. What I mean by wrong date, is the date on the xAxis and the hover tooltip do not match up.

Comment: Right. But there is nothing to indicate that they should. The **axis** is a scale. The labels appear at a set interval, defaulting to first of the month (for the data illustrated). The **tooltip** shows the details of a specific data point. If your goal is to make sure each x axis label related directly to a point, you can use the **tickPositions** property to achieve this.

Comment: If you want an example of how to use the tickPositions to achieve this, post an example of the data (with the dates) that you want to plot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use below option:

```
 Highcharts.setOptions({
        global: {
            useUTC: false
        }
    });
```